# Question 10.35 (b) Tom Apostol Mathematical analysis

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

Question: If f is measurable on $\mathbb{R}$ , prove that for every open subset A of $\mathbb{R}$ the set $f^{-1}(A)$ is measurable.

I have proved in (a) that for every real a $f^{-1} ((a, +\infty)) =\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcap_{k=n}^{\infty} s_k^{-1} (( a+1/n ,\infty))$ holds when  f is measurable but now I don't know how to use this to prove that  forCharacterstic function of the set $f^{-1}(A)$
there exists a sequence of step function ${t_n(x)}$ such that ${t_n(x)} \to$ Characterstic function?

Just outline the hints ,  no need to solve it.

Comment: Measure theory isn't my forte. I would write $A$ as a countable union of open intervals. Then (a) could be used...

Comment: What is your definition of measurable function?

Comment: @QuantumSpace f is called measurable if there exists a sequence of step functions {$s_n (x)$} such that lim n $ \to \infty  s_n{x} $ = f(x) for almost every x.